# Google Chrome sending background requests without me visiting the page

Tags: google-chrome

I today noticed a strange Google Chrome behaviour.
In the last few days, I visited one particular site let's say example.com very often (work related site). The site is SSL enabled and visiting example.com redirects me to https://www.example.com.

I was developing and debugging on localhost today and had Fiddler opened. I suddenly noticed request to example.com in Fiddler which redirected to https://www.example.com, followed by a series of HTTPS Tunnel requests to www.example.com (I did not had decrypt HTTPS traffic option enabled in Fiddler, so only got TUNNEL requests without underlying page url).

I noticed the User-Agent header for these reqeusts and they were originating from Chrome. But I did not open example.com site anywhere in the last hour in Chrome. I checked Chrome's history and yes, I did not open that site recently.

Is this expected Google Chrome behavior (some sort of pre-fetching). My version is 19.0.1084.56. My computer is not infected as it's a hardened with a series of measures and the activity itself does not look suspicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior for Chrome and was apparently added earlier this year. http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2145148/google-touts-website-prefetching-chrome

Comment: Thanks Stephanie, I discusussed this question here also:
http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-discuss
And got this very useful link:
chrome://net-internals/#prerender